# File downloaded by curl but not by node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, http, curl, http-headers

So I'm trying to download a file through nodejs that opens fine in the browser, and even downloads fine in tools like curl.
But nodejs just fails for some reason to download the file. I tried downloading the file through the `request` module in node and through a node cli module called `download-cli`. Both of them fail with either a 400 or 404 response yet the file downloads fine through regular tools like curl.

What could be the issue? I have tried setting the user-agent to that of Firefox (where it opens just fine) but that doesn't do the trick. I'm assuming the problem isn't about the user-agent anyway since curl doesn't have its own user-agent.

The url in question can be any url from alicdn but lets take this one as an example:
[https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-часы-поддержка-синхронизации-notifier-sim-карты-подключение-bluetooth-для-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-notifier-sim-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-bluetooth-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg)

Here's the response by running the above url through the node `download-cli` tool and the `Invoke-WebRequest` tool in powershell.

```
PS C:\code> download https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-часы-поддержка-син
хронизации-notifier-sim-карты-подключение-bluetooth-для-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg
Couldn't connect to https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-часы-поддержка-синхронизации-notifier-sim-карты-подключение-bluetooth-для-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg (404)
PS C:\code> curl https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-часы-поддержка-синхрон
изации-notifier-sim-карты-подключение-bluetooth-для-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {255, 216, 255, 224...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-Application-Context: fileserver2-download:prod:7001
                    From-Req-Dns-Type: NA,NA
                    SERVED-FROM: 72.247.178.95
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Network_Info: DE_FRANKFURT_16509
                    Timing-Allow-Ori...
Headers           : {[X-Application-Context, fileserver2-download:prod:7001], [From-Req-Dns-Type, NA,NA], [SERVED-FROM, 72.247.178.95],
                    [Connection, keep-alive]...}
RawContentLength  : 114927
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to download the file from Node? It's impossible to answer if we don't know how are you trying to do this.

Comment: @serge1peshcoff I have tried downloading through all kinds of code like using the native http module, using request module and some others. The code worked fine for 99% cases but failed here. See the answer for the actual reason this was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tried downloading the file through node's native http module, I tried downloading through the popular `request` module AND I tried downloading through a node based cli tool called `download-cli`. Everyone of them had the same response. 
So I fired up Wireshark and tried to see exactly where the requests are different and it turns out that tools like `curl` and `Invoke-WebRequest` escape the path before making a GET request but node's native module doesn't do that. That was the only difference. Using the escaped url works fine.

Invoke-WebRequest's GET path:

```
GET /kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-notifier-sim-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-bluetooth-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

Node's GET path:

```
GET /kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-G0AK-?>445@6:0-A8=E@>=870F88-notifier-sim-:0@BK-?>4:;NG5=85-bluetooth-4;O-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

why you didnt do it :

```
$url='https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ftVmPVXXXXXUXVXXq6xXFXXXG/Langtek-smart-watch-gt12-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-notifier-sim-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-bluetooth-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile C:\temp\android-apple-iphone.jpg_640x640.jpg
```